# Read the Value of an Item in a listbox

Tags: c#, listview, listbox, windows-store-apps

I'm developing a small windows store application in C# where I have populated the **values** and **content** for a *listbox* using the following code snippet.

code 1 : adds the song title as a *item* to a *listbox*, using the Song *class* to create the *item*

```
    private void addTitles(string title, int value) 
    {
        Song songItem = new Song(); 
        songItem.Text = title;
        songItem.Value = value;
        listbox1.Items.Add(songItem); // adds the 'songItem' as an Item to listbox
    }
```

code 2 : Song *class* which is used to set values to each *item* ('songItem')

```
public class Song
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

Population content to the *listbox* is functioning currently.

What I want is to get the 'Value' of each *item* on a Click event, on run-time.

For that purpose, how can I read(extract) the **Value** of the selected Item in the *listbox*, in C#? ( Value is the songItem.Value )

code 3 :  I have tried this code, as trying to figure out a solution, but it didn't work

```
 private void listbox1_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           Int selectedItemValue = listbox1.SelectedItem.Value();
        }
```

Therefore it would be really grateful if someone can help me, as I'm an Amateur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not sure about the "TappedRoutedEventArgs", but I would do

```
private void listbox1_tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           var selectedSong = (Song)listbox1.SelectedItem;
           if (selectedSong != null) {
              var val = selectedSong.Value;
              }
        }
```

because `SelectedItem` is an `Object` (which doesn't know about the `Value` property), so you have to cast it to a `Song` first.

By the way, `Value` is a `property`, not a `method`, so you don't need the parenthesis.

Comment: Appreciate for the response, I modified your given code by casting the value to an Int and got the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
Song song=listbox1.SelectedItem as Song;
```

or this:

```
 var selected = listbox1.SelectedValue as Song;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
if (listbox1.SelectedRows.Count>0){
      Song song=(Song)listbox1.SelectedItem;
  int value=song.Value;
}
```